# C#: Accessing variable from another method, modifying it, returning it to the original method

Tags: c#, variables, methods

Probably a very simple question, and maybe I'm not even doing it right in the first place. Done some research and having trouble understanding the second part.

Let's say I have two methods in C#, and I want to send the value of that variable to another method. This is how I've accomplished it, sending variable1s value to method 2

```
public void methodOne(string variable1)
{
    variable1 = "testing";
    myClass p = new myClass();
    p.methodTwo(variable1);
}
public void methodTwo(string variable1)
{
    Console.Write(variable1);
}
```

So this sends the information in variable1 from methodOne to methodTwo.

But what if I wanted to modify the variable in methodTwo, and then send it back to methodOne? Would I just do the same exact thing in methodTwo and utilize this again?

```
        myClass p = new myClass();
        p.methodOne(variable1);
```

My issue is obviously if I utilize that code, I'd get stuck in an infinite loop of going back and forth unless I added a break condition. It makes me think maybe I'm not even correctly considering how to do this, and there's an easier way I'm missing.

Comment: Ok, not sure why method 2 is in a different class than method 1,or if that's what you intended, but that's what it looks like you want. But regardless of whether or not it's in a different class, pass the variable ByRef. Do a Google search for c# ByRef and see what you come up with.

Comment: If you still can't figure it out and still want help, let me know.

Comment: Hi @David.Warwick, they are in the same class, sorry for the confusion! I will look up by reference now and see what I come up with. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, it should simply be ref, not byref. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pass the variable ByRef, using the ref keyword.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            

        Method1();
    }

    private static void Method1()
    {
        int myVar = 5;
        Console.WriteLine($"myVar in Method1: {myVar}"); // 5

        Method2(ref myVar);

        Console.WriteLine($"myVar in Method2: {myVar}"); // 10
    }

    private static void Method2(ref int AnotherVar)
    {
        AnotherVar = 10;
    }
    
}
}
```